# Google Drive API - Copy an existing Spreadsheet file and set the "title" using JavaScript Client API

Tags: javascript, google-api, client-side, google-drive-api

I am working through the Google Javascript Client API Sample here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html

I am testing the Google Drive API, specifically the gapi.client.drive.files.copy method. I can get it to copy a file to my Drive, but I cannot get it to change the TITLE. Here is the code:

```
function makeApiCall() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
          var request = gapi.client.drive.files.copy({

        "title": "New Landmax SS from API 5",
        "fileId": "0Ap_i-ZEiVl0pdDhYbFpxSFc5ZW1nYlMwV2poSXhTSGc"
          });
          request.execute(function(resp) {
                result = resp;
          });
        });
      }
```

However, I can get it to work using the Google API Explorer, but it does not give the JavaScript Code. So it is probably a small syntax issue. Suggestions?  Unfortunately, none of the Drive API sample code uses the new(er) Javascript Client API, just server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching the Google I/O video again, I now seem to have the syntax working to copy a Google Spreadsheet with a new name:

```
var url = 'drive/v2/files/0Ap_i-ZEiVl0pdDhYbFpxSFc5ZW1nYlMwV2poSXhTSGc/copy'

var request = gapi.client.request({
'path':url,
'method': 'POST',
'body':{
    'title': 'New Landmax SS from API 6'
    }
    });
```

The mix-up occurs between REST requests and JsonRPC, which are similar but not the same.  The REST version above works. The original question was JsonRPC which I could not get to work.  If someone can make the RPC version work and explain when to use either version, I think a lot of developers would be grateful.

This is very cool stuff! And the imagination is firing up.  I noticed that Google App Scripts, that were in the original Spreadsheet, were also copied over.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
/**
* Copy an existing file.
*
* @param {String} originFileId ID of the origin file to copy.
* @param {String} copyTitle Title of the copy.
*/
function copyFile(originFileId, copyTitle) {
    var body = {'title': copyTitle};
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.copy({
       'fileId': originFileId,
       'resource': body
     });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log('Copy ID: ' + resp.id);
  });
}
```

Hope this will help.

Source - [Google Drive SDK Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy)

Answer (score 0):

Check the request and response from the API console against the request and response you are sending with the client library. I suspect they are not the same.

What you will need is something more like:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.copy({
  "fileId": "0Ap_i-ZEiVl0pdDhYbFpxSFc5ZW1nYlMwV2poSXhTSGc",
  "body":    {
    "title": "New Landmax SS from API 5",
  }
});
```

The distinction here is that fileId is a parameter to the API method call, whereas the title is part of the JSON resource to send with the method.

Comment: Thanks Ali, I tried that exact syntax as well. And I looked at both the Google API Explorer (GAPIE) and My Code (MC) in Firebug. From what I can see, the GAPIE is using a simple REST with "title" as the only item in the payload, while MC (following the JS Client API sample), is sending a RPC Json Post Request. They are similar and the response is similar, so it may be a bug with the RPC style. If you have a minute, try the sample code yourself, swapping out for drive.file.copy.